# Changing Maven profile while running with JRebel

Tags: maven, jrebel, maven-profiles

I started using JRebel just moment ago. In my current setup launch JBoss instance from Eclipse and I use command line maven to deploy. I was wondering whether it would be anyhow possible to avoid redeployment when I need to change from test-A profile to test-B profile. Profiles are used here to set several configuration values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JRebel, you should forget about Maven as there's no need to build the package after every change. 
If profiles are used only for configurations, why not to make the changes to the configuration files directly? Depending on the nature of the configuration files these can be handled by JRebel. What are those configuration files?

Comment: Most likely I was thinking too complicated way. Editing the file directly should do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change profiles for already running Maven instance. But you can activate specific profiles on Maven startup using system properties.